# Write a process with 0 idle memory

Tags: process

I see that the daemons in my PC's process list idle with 0 memory usage. I want my daemons to run like that, so how is it done?

Comment: That are probably kernel threads. They're actually _require memory_, but kernel shows it as zero because it's kernel itself. Everything, even very small asm hello world, is using memory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would help if you included an excerpt from your ps output.  However, if you are talking about things like this:

```
USER       PID %CPU %MEM    VSZ   RSS TTY      STAT START   TIME COMMAND
root         1  0.0  0.0  35028  4416 ?        Ss   Nov05   0:07 /sbin/init
root         2  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Nov05   0:00 [kthreadd]
root         3  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Nov05   2:43 [ksoftirqd/0]
root         5  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   Nov05   0:00 [kworker/0:0H]
root         8  0.4  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Nov05  73:44 [rcu_preempt]
root         9  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Nov05   0:00 [rcu_sched]
root        10  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Nov05   0:00 [rcu_bh]
...
```

Then anything in brackets is actually a kernel thread.  The way to do that is write an lkm, but that's probably not what you want to do.  I guess the other thing you could do to get RSS down would be to write a user-level daemon that just sleeps, and hence will eventually get paged out.  VSZ will still be non-zero, though.

Comment: You're right about the kernel threads. But my daemons do sleep and they still take 1MB of memory. I wonder if there's any API for quickly paging a sleeping process? Or perhaps using a special low overhead language for the daemon and using it to call the main program?

Comment: @LikeSue The thing is, what ps reports and how much physical memory are required are not exactly the same thing.  Even if ps reports 0 RSS, there is still some memory for kernel data structures.  As for the 1MB, linux won't page your daemon out until it actually needs the memory.  You can try an experiment: write a program that allocates 128MiB, writes to each page (to force allocation), and then calls pause().  Then write another program that uses all available memory in a loop and forces paging.  This should cause the first program to get paged out.